# Google C# Api Beta 1.6 Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

Trying to Authenticate and access Google Calendar Service with C# Beta v1.6 SDK
and something does not look right

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis;
using Google.Apis.Services;



var uc = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets() { 
                    ClientId = string.Empty, 
                    ClientSecret = string.Empty }, 
                    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, 
                    "user", 
                    CancellationToken.None);

var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = uc,
            ApplicationName = "Google Calendar Test"
        });
```

In particular this line: **HttpClientInitializer = uc**,

I'm following Task vb example: [Tasks VB Sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples)

The error message that I get is this:

**Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Google.Apis.Http.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Answer (score 0):

function `AuthorizeAsync` is async, so it returns `Task<T>` not exact result. In your case you need to get property `Result` of return `Task<T>`.

```
var uc = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets() { 
                ClientId = string.Empty, 
                ClientSecret = string.Empty }, 
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, 
                "user", 
                CancellationToken.None).Result;
```